# What is average unpooling?

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

I'm working on an implementation of a paper and I haven't been able to find a description of average unpooling. I tried using max unpooling instead and my results were not great.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the link to the paper to give us a bit more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go backward for max-pooling you keep track of the position of the maximum:

$$ X = \begin{bmatrix}
1 && 2 \\
3 && 4
\end{bmatrix} \quad \rightarrow \quad dZ *\begin{bmatrix}
0 && 0 \\
0 && 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

This gives you the position of the input value that ultimately influenced the cost/output. The gradient will then be "propagated" back to this value.

For average pooling, all values influence the cost equally and therefore it should look like this:

$$ dZ = z \quad \rightarrow  \quad \begin{bmatrix}
z/n && z/n \\
z/n && z/n
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $n$ depends on the filter size, here $n=4$.

The gradient gets distributed evenly back to all input values.